# Registering NiFi template in Kylo with input options

Tags: templates, apache-nifi, kylo

I am trying to create a template in NiFi just like a data ingest template which provide by kylo.

Basically I want to allow user to select input data source it can be database or a file. If he selects file and then database processor should automatically gets disabled.

I have create a template in NiFi and imported it kylo, but while creating feed It does not show the feed input option.

[image]

How I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

While registering the template, in the "Input Properties" section, you have to select which properties have to be shown in feed creation UI for user input i.e. Enable "Allow user input?"

Attached the screenshot for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here would be to use the **RouteOnAttribute**  as the step after the Data Source/ Data type is chosen. 
  This way you don't have to overthink it.

Comment: Actually the question is related on the Kylo side. Kylo lets you take care of which input processor needs to be disabled based on what the user chose at the feed creation time.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on Kylo for around 3 months now and surely know a thing or two about it. 
While starting a Feed, Kylo asks you for which source you want to start a feed no matter you have a single processor or multiple which can act as a data producer or fetcher. Once you select one and start a feed, rest of the source processors get disabled automatically by Kylo in the resultant deployment of feed.